# Laravel 5 on IIS7 does not work with web.config

Tags: windows, laravel, iis, laravel-5

I have a simple Laravel 5 app. It was developed on Xampp, and worked perfectly. I copied it onto the production server, and it does not work. Something is wrong with the web.config file, because if I remove it, then the app works perfectly with index.php/path

My webconfig is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^(.*)/$" ignoreCase="false" />
          <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="/{R:1}" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="Rule 2" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^" ignoreCase="false" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

The app is located at a subfolder of the website and I cannot create a new site, but I can restart IIS as needed. I really don't know IIS very well (in fact I hate it), so I don't know where to check, but since the app works without the web.config, I assume it must be the culprit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IIS Needs to have the `URL Rewrite Module` for the Laravel `web.config` to work.

On XAMPP, it will work out of the box as the Apache `mod_rewrite` module is included and most of the configuration settings are already provided by XAMPP.

> Microsoft URL Rewrite.
>   Download it from [here](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite)

Comment: It does not let me download it. It always takes me to the web app gallery.

Comment: Ok, I downloaded and installed it from here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7435
And now it works.

Comment: My bad, the links are at the bottom of the page that I have provided. (WebPI/x64/x86) Glad that you were able to resolve your problem. Cheers! :)