# how to remove public/index.php in laravel hosting on IIS windows server

Tags: php, laravel, iis

Server person created a subdomain in IIS server. But when i access the website like   suppose

```
subdomain.example.in   //Not working
subdomain.example.in/public   //working... but when i login it shows 404 not found
subdomain.example.in/public/index.php  //everything working.
```

I have search around google and i have added .htaccess in root folder like below:-

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule    ^$    public/    [L]
RewriteRule    (.*) public/$1    [L]
</IfModule>

 ---------------------web.config----- in public folder-----
 <configuration>
 <system.webServer>
  <rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Imported Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^(.*)/$" ignoreCase="false" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="/{R:1}" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="Imported Rule 2" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^" ignoreCase="false" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

But above code not working at all. Even i have tried the rename server.php to index.php  adn copy htacess file from public to root directory. Still its not working. Can anyone help me how can i resolve this issue. I am using IIS windows server.. I have done many websites and uploaded in Capnel i just put htacess on root directory then it start working but its not working on IIS server. Please help me

Comment: You need a web.config file for IIS. See: http://cbsa.com.br/tools/online-convert-htaccess-to-web-config.aspx

Comment: yes web.config file already present in public folder

Comment: Edit your web.config file to point to /public

Comment: @Joshua please tell me where to do modifications in web.config i have added the web.config code

Comment: The .htaccess file is Apache only, It means nothing to IIS. Note that changes to your web.config file have no effect until you restart IIS for the domain.

Comment: @Ultimater I will ask server person to restart the server but firstly  tell me where to do modifications in web.config file

Comment: Take a loot at this link https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40305426/laravel-5-on-iis7-does-not-work-with-web-config&ved=2ahUKEwigu42vptPfAhVGJ1AKHbqcBcQQjjgwAnoECAYQAQ&usg=AOvVaw0kuGAAExc3A0bFbiedQqUe&cshid=1546576522816

Comment: @Joshua can server person do this thing or i need to do coding in it.. Please help me i have no idea about iis server

Comment: Since you have a server guy, why not let the person fix the issue inorder to avoid server misconfiguration

Comment: It looks like you want to make `public` the new directory root so you can store stuff under it. I'd avoid silent redirects and simply ask them to point the domain to `/public` instead.

Comment: @Joshua ok i will ask him if we will resolve